# Downloading file is corrupted - header

Tags: php

I have be trying to figure out what is wrong but every time i download the image and try to open it, it says that the file is corrupt.

$h is the path which is pulled from the database, the $h displays the image on the page successfully but I dont get why it wont download. Any ideas ??

```
header("Pragma: public"); // required   
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers  
header('Content-Length: '. filesize("../".$h));  
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');  
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.md5($h).$ext.'"');  
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary');  
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');  

readfile("../".$h);
```

Comment: Have you tried saving the downloaded file and comparing it to what's on the server?

Comment: Seems like your header data is incorrect somehow, look at the md5 hash and the filesize.

Comment: yea i can right click on the image and it will download fine. Hmm i assumed it was the header, but cant find out whats up with it. will remove the hash and see what it does.

Comment: this isn't the problem but it also wouldn't hurt to remove the Content-Transfer-Encoding header field. It doesn't exist in HTTP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe try to add the following 2 commands before your readfile line.

```
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
```

These lines were in the example for the PHP docs on readfile.

Comment: Thanks! ob_clean() alone did the trick for me. With flush it just showed content.

Comment: Yes, I also needed to remove flush().

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$localPath = realpath("../$h");
if (!file_exists($localPath)) {
  exit("Cannot find file located at '$localPath'");
}

header('Pragma: public'); // required   
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($localPath));  
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');  
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.md5($localPath).'.'.$ext.'"');  
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');  
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);  
header('Cache-Control: private', false); // required for certain browsers  

readfile($localPath);
exit;
```

Comment: tried it and it downloads but still cannot open it. Do you think it might be file permissions ? Running my code on wamp if that makes a difference anyhow.

Comment: The most likely answer here is that you have some leading/trailing whitespace in your file, before or after the `<?php ?>` tags. These should be the very first and very last characters in your script. You can safely omit the `?>` closing tag. You may also have a call to `echo`, `print` etc before the code above - remember you cannot write anything to the output buffer apart from the file data when doing this. Also ensure you have called `exit`/`die` **immediately** after the `readfile()` call.

Comment: Ahhh how stupid, had a white space after the ?> works like a dream now.. thanks DaveRandom

Comment: @Jason as I say you can safely omit the `?>` tag and PHP will not complain. This helps to avoid this sort of problem.